# How can I use pandas explode on string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataFrame in pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'questionId':[1, 2],'answer':['["Trustful", "Curious", "Nervous"]', "very good"]})
df.explode('answer')
```

The actual answer:

```
questionId  answer
0   1   ["Trustful", "Curious", "Nervous"]
1   2   very good
```

**My desired answer:**

```
questionId  answer
0   1   Trustful
0   1   Curious
0   1   Nervous
1   2   very good
```

Can you help me out with how can I convert

```
'["Trustful", "Curious", "Nervous"]' to ["Trustful", "Curious", "Nervous"]
```

so that I can get the answer I am looking for?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `str.findall`

```
s = df.answer.str.findall('"([^"]*)"')
out = df.assign(answer = np.where(s.astype(bool),s,df.answer)).explode('answer')
out
   questionId     answer
0           1   Trustful
0           1    Curious
0           1    Nervous
1           2  very good
```